# To open Eclipse , show this message

Tags: android

```
[2014-12-05 10:01:17 - MySaluteBd] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2014-12-05 10:01:17 - MySaluteBd] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2014-12-05 10:01:17 - MySaluteBd] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2014-12-05 10:01:17 - MySaluteBd] Versions found are:
[2014-12-05 10:01:17 - MySaluteBd] Path: /media/anamul/Audio World/Tutorial/linux create apps android/appcompat_v7/libs/android-support-v4.jar
[2014-12-05 10:01:17 - MySaluteBd]  Length: 758727
[2014-12-05 10:01:17 - MySaluteBd]  SHA-1: efec67655f6db90757faa37201efcee2a9ec3507
[2014-12-05 10:01:17 - MySaluteBd] Path: /home/anamul/MySaluteBd/libs/android-support-v4.jar
[2014-12-05 10:01:17 - MySaluteBd]  Length: 995386
[2014-12-05 10:01:17 - MySaluteBd]  SHA-1: a13f8fe2c278737e2f0b6fcf00f6b2ae4034aacf
[2014-12-05 10:01:17 - MySaluteBd] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Comment: Try to put android-support-v4.jar top most library project and remove from other projects.

Comment: how ? tell me procedure ?

Comment: have you used any library project ?

Comment: okay just try to remove android-support-v4.jar from MySaluteBd lib folder.

Comment: emove android-support-v4.jar from MySaluteBd lib folder. now?

Comment: clean and run your project.

Comment: now show this message : error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: Goto this path : android-sdk\extras\android\support\ and get android-support-v7.jar  now replace  android-support-v4.jar with android-support-v7.jar in appcompat_v7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have used external android libraries may be this problems occurs .
You can use like this in your libraries and projects : write click on project >> Android Tools >> Add Supported Library.